# List items that don't have specific "SKU"?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, vba

All I am trying to do is return a list of Freezer Accounts that don't have a specific SKU.
Here is an example of the data:

[image: SO18071323 question example]

Suppose I want to return all of the Freezer Accounts that do not have the SKU (R3552S). 
The result should be:

F0000563
F0002365

What is the easiest way to get this list? I tried an IF statement, then compare the tables but that doesn't seem to be working correctly. Also tried a pivot table, but not sure I know how to use it correctly. Also tried VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tedious but fairly simple with a helper column, with `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=COUNTIFS(B:B,"<>R3552S",A:A,A2),A2,"")` in it and copied down (assuming Freezer Account is in ColumnA Row1 and no gaps). Add a label to the helper column (say E in ColumnE) and select it, Data > Sort & Filter - Advanced, Copy to another location (say G1), check Unique records only. Delete G1 and Column E and sort ColumnF.

*Edit re supplementary*

The formula and process is relatively cumbersome even for a single SKU exclusion but seemed to match the question's requirement better than a PivotTable would have. However where there are two exclusions (or even perhaps more) a PivotTable is very much simpler and more 'powerful', though it gives visual results rather than a list of exclusions:

[image: SO180171323 example].

The pale blue is the original answer and the darker blue the answer to the supplemental addition, so combined that is `F0000563`. The 'power' comes from the same table offering answers to many more questions also. For example *take in account 2 SKU's* could mean just `F0000563` ("Which have neither?") as I have assumed but the answer (all four Freezer Accounts) is also evident for "Which do not have both?"

Comment: That worked really nice. Thank you. How would you change it to take in account 2 SKU's? I tried adding adding an OR("<>R3552S","<>M0202L"), but that doesn't return the right result.